# How do I pass variables from a postgresql script to an external script

Tags: postgresql, psql

How do I pass variables from as postgresql script to an external script in a right way? It seems, that the variable interpolation will work well, if I use `\echo '...'`, but not with `` \echo `...` `` and `\!`. Here example code lines:

```sql
-- set the variables
\set DB_SCHEMA     GT1
\set GEO_VAR_EPSG  '32632'
\set GEO_VAR_TMAX  '250'
-- :DBNAME is a local psql variable
-- print via echo '...'
\echo 'CALL mk-exp-position.pl' :DBNAME :GEO_VAR_TMAX :GEO_VAR_EPSG :DB_SCHEMA.exp_position :DB_SCHEMA.exp_transect
-- try to call some external stuff via \echo `...`
\echo `./mk-exp-position.pl :DBNAME :GEO_VAR_TMAX :GEO_VAR_EPSG :DB_SCHEMA.exp_position :DB_SCHEMA.exp_transect`
-- try to call external script via \! ...
\! ./mk-exp-position.pl :DBNAME :GEO_VAR_TMAX :GEO_VAR_EPSG :DB_SCHEMA.exp_position :DB_SCHEMA.exp_transect
```

The perl scriptlet that reads the params from the command line to some variables and print them:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

# check parameter count, give help and die
if ( $#ARGV < 4) {
 die " USAGE: $0 DB_NAME MAX_DIST EPSG SRC_TAB DST_TAB\n"
}

# read assign the command line parameter array to some variables
my ($DB_NAME, $MAX_DIST, $EPSG, $TAB_IN, $TAB_OUT) = @ARGV;

# print the variables to the stdout
print "#FILL.TABLE $TAB_OUT FROM $TAB_IN IN $DB_NAME PARAM MAX_DIST=$MAX_DIST EPSG=$EPSG\n";
```

And the result \echo 'CALL...':

```
CALL mk-exp-position.pl daisi_2017_06_06 250 32632 GT1.exp_position GT1.exp_transect
```

And the result \echo `...` or \! ... :

```
#FILL.TABLE :DB_SCHEMA.exp_transect FROM :DB_SCHEMA.exp_position IN :DBNAME PARAM MAX_DIST=:GEO_VAR_CMAX EPSG=:GEO_VAR_EPSG
```

Regards

Comment: Um ... \echo isn't designed for calling external programs.  You're kinda on your own, there.

Comment: @FuzzChef \! do'nt works too. Hm in general I'm struggeling a little bit with the role understanding of the psql tool as a kind of "shell" with variables and "shell out mechanisms". Some things work a little bit like \echo 'DATA SESSION DATE: ' \`date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"\`. But interpolation of "variables" declared with \set or setting from a shell out not. So what to choose? Is a complete encapsulation of the psql code by a different interface (DBI) better?

Comment: Well, psql isn't really intended as a full-service tool for executing tasks involving external programs.  It's primarily a CLI for the database -- it's a command shell, NOT a programming shell. Really, you're a lot better off using a program with a database driver, and having that call database code.